# Emulate Android in Swing

Tags: java, android, swing, android-emulator

I want to be able to run my Android code/app on Windows/Mac/Linux/etc. but not use an emulator, as they are slow/cumbersome.

I want a real Java SE app, but to reuse my Android code.
My idea is to make an Android emulator using Swing, read the layout files and create the widgets in Swing and map between the 2 UI event models, life cycle, and library classes.

Question is, does such a thing exist already, I googled it, but could not find anything.

Otherwise I will start an open source project for it myself. Anyone interested in helping is more than welcome.

Comment: How is it going to be faster and less cumbersome than an emulator? If you have a different goal, that's fine.

Comment: I agree with muratgu.  You're going to make your own android emulator, which means you have to do all the things that make the android emulator slow.  Are you thinking it will be fast because you're better at this than Google?

Comment: It will be faster because it is not emulating a device, just mapping the user interface into Swing components, so it will look/feel like a desktop Java app, but reuse Android app code

Comment: Surely someone has already done this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I created an open source project "Swingdroid" that lets you run Android apps and Java swing desktop applications.

You don't need to use an emulator or change any code. It loads Android layout files and activities and renders them using Swing.

On GitHub here,
https://github.com/BotLibre/BotLibre/tree/master/swingdroid

Comment: How to use this?

Comment: Copy your code from your Android project to a Java SE project and add the Swingdroid jar to fix the Android dependencies.  You should be able to then create a main method to run your Android main view.  Since Android depends on the generated R class, you will need to define this as well.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with @muratgu. But, if you just want to parse Android layouts (views) xml files and render them using Java Swing, this is possible and this has already been implemented, before deciding to make your own implementation, you'd better check the wysiwyg feature of UI editor in Android Studio.